# How to show error page(deny_info) squid proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

For example I have the following ACLs

```
acl mortales src "/etc/squid/listas/mortales"
acl bloquear url_regex "/etc/listas/bloqueo"

http_access allow mortales !bloqueo
error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/en/
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED mortales
```

The problem is with the browser, cause squid does block the sites of the block list but it does not show me the custom squid error pages, it only shows me the generic error pages of the web browser. I found the next information on this web site "http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CustomErrors".
I read thats new versions of browsers for example firefox dont showing error pages custom, but display their own generic error pages.

I want to show the error pages of squid proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration will work for http connections but it will not work for https connections.

I have researched this question myself, and have failed to find a solution that allows the configurations to work over https connections in squid.

I have attached the following links which provide some answers as to why it is not possible or not advisable if using Ssl Bump.

[Browser behaviour handling](https://serverfault.com/questions/832810/custom-error-page-deny-info-for-https)

[Man in the middle - Ssl Bump](https://serverfault.com/questions/639650/redirect-a-https-connect-using-squid)

Comment: Thank you very much for your information

Comment: Hi Morbo Morbo, did you end up using custom error dir with custom error files?
Please let me know, as I'm have  issue with squid proxy not displaying the defualt error pages from /usr/share/squid/errors/en/ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
my acl config:

error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/en/

deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED bad_urls
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED denyKeywords
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED regex_bad_urls